# Node-template for stand-alone blockchains with POS babe consensus

Tags: substrate-node-template, babe, pos

Is there a node-template for babe consensus tracking all the changes and updates as it does to substrate-node-template which follows aura consensus.

For eg., polkadot-v0.9.24 changes are already integrated to substrate-node-template repo. But there is no way I can find the changes related to babe consensus and its changes related to polkadot-v0.9.24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, there is the `node-template` with Aura:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6a946fc36d68b89599d7ca1ab03803d10c78468c/bin/node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs#L280

...and there is `node` with Babe here:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6a946fc36d68b89599d7ca1ab03803d10c78468c/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1583

Both are in-sync with latest release.

Comment: The template is functioning smoothly under POS consensus. However, I think it incorporates several extra pallets. Could you identify the redundant pallets integrated into the template that can be removed without disrupting its functionality?